# Scala iterate over map and turn singleton List into just the singleton

Tags: scala

I am trying to extract a value of type List[T] to just T in a Map. So for instance:

```
val c = Map(1->List(1), 2-> List(2), 3->List(3));
```

would turn into

```
Map(1->1,2->2,3->3);
```

Here is what I have written so far:

```
val Some(values) = request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.foreach {
  case (key,value) =>
    Map(key->value.head);  
};
```

and here is the error I am receiving:

```
constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type; found : (T1, T2) required: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Seq[String]]
```

EDIT: This is ocurring wrt to this line:

```
case (key,value) =>
```

EDIT2: 
request.body.asFormUrlEncoded example output

```
Some(Map(test -> List(324)))
Some(Map(SpO2 -> List(456), ETCO2 -> List(123)))
```

Comment: Don't use semicolons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure that you will always have exactly one element in the list? If so, you should do this, which is clear, and has the benefit that it will throw an error if you get a bad list (doesn't have exactly one element) by accident.

```
c.map { case (k, List(v)) => k -> v }
// Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3)
```

If your lists can have more than one element, and you just want the first, you can do this (which will error on empty lists):

```
val d = Map(1 -> List(1), 2 -> List(2,4,6), 3 -> List(3))
d.map { case (k, List(v, _*)) => k -> v }
// Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3)
```

If your lists may not have exactly one element, and you want to ignore any non-singleton lists instead of throwing errors, use `collect` instead of `map`:

```
val e = Map(1 -> List(1), 2 -> List(2,4,6), 3 -> List(3), 4 -> List())
e.collect { case (k, List(v)) => k -> v }
// Map(1 -> 1, 3 -> 3)
```

---

As for your code:

```
val Some(values) = request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.foreach {
  case (key,value) =>
    Map(key->value.head);  
};
```

This doesn't really make any sense.

First off, `foreach` doesn't return anything, so assigning its result to a variable will never work.  You probably want this to be a `map` instead, so that it returns a collection.

Second, your use of `Some` makes it seem like you don't understand `Option`s, so you might want to read up on that.

Third, if you want the result to be a Map (a collection of pairs), then you'll just want to return the pair, `key->value.head`, and not a Map.

Fourth, if you're getting errors matching on `case (key,value)`, then probably `asFormUrlEncoded` doesn't actually return a collection of pairs.  You should see what its type actually is.

Lastly, the semicolons are unnecessary.  You should remove them.

---

**EDIT** based on your comment:

Since `request.body.asFormUrlEncoded` actually returns things like `Some(Map("test" -> List(324)))`, here is how your code should look.

If `asFormUrlEncoded` might return `None`, and you don't have any way of handling that, then you should guard against it:

```
val a = Some(Map("test" -> List(324)))
val value = a match {
  case Some(m) => m.collect { case (k, List(v)) => k -> v }
  case None => sys.error("expected something, got nothing")
}
```

If you're sure that `asFormUrlEncoded` will already return `Some`, then you can just do this:

```
val a = Some(Map("test" -> List(324)))
val Some(value) = a.map(_.collect { case (k, List(v)) => k -> v })
```

Comment: i just tried all three of these, and i still get the error I made in the OP.

Comment: I tried it with what I had in the OP. I changed the case statement, and then from .map to .collect

Comment: Here is an example of what request.body.asFormUrlEncoded prints out to: Some(Map(test -> List(324)))